# suppressWarnings() doesn't work with pipe operator

Tags: r, magrittr

I am trying to suppress warnings by using the `suppressWarnings()` function.

Surprisingly, it removes warnings when used normally, but it fails to do so when you use the pipe `%>%` operator.

Here is some example code :

```
library(magrittr)

c("1", "2", "ABC") %>% as.numeric()
# [1]  1  2 NA
# Warning message:
# In function_list[[k]](value) : NAs introduced by coercion

c("1", "2", "ABC") %>% as.numeric() %>% suppressWarnings
# [1]  1  2 NA
# Warning message:
# In function_list[[i]](value) : NAs introduced by coercion

suppressWarnings(c("1", "2", "ABC") %>% as.numeric())
# [1]  1  2 NA
```

Why does it work with parenthesis but not with pipe operator ?
Is there a specific syntax I should use to make it work ?

Comment: Another workaround could be `c("1", "2", "ABC") %>% {suppressWarnings(as.numeric(.))}`

Comment: I don't expect there is a way to do what you are trying to do.  The pipe operator takes the object returned by the preceding call and pushes it forward to the succeeding call.  Warnings are not part of the objects; they are cast when they occur, and cannot be passed from one function to the next.  I think the most readable solution is to wrap `suppressWarnings` around the full chain of calls.

Comment: I guess you would have same problem with `try` (to capture errors)

Comment: I think @Benjamin answers the first question very well and thus make the second one irrelevant. Thanks sir !

Comment: if occurring in an RMarkdown script, you could add `warning = FALSE` to the chunk options.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One solution would be to use the `%T>%` pipes to modify options (from `magrittr`, not included in `dplyr`!)

```
c("1", "2", "ABC") %T>% {options(warn=-1)} %>% as.numeric() %T>% {options(warn=0)}
```

You could also use `purrr::quietly`, not so pretty in this case...

```
library(purr)
c("1", "2", "ABC") %>% {quietly(as.numeric)}() %>% extract2("result")
c("1", "2", "ABC") %>% map(quietly(as.numeric)) %>% map_dbl("result")
```

for the sake of completeness, here are also @docendo-discimus 's solution and OP's own workaround

```
c("1", "2", "ABC") %>% {suppressWarnings(as.numeric(.))} 
suppressWarnings(c("1", "2", "ABC") %>% as.numeric())
```

And I'm stealing @Benjamin's comment as to why the original try doesn't work :

> Warnings are not part of the objects; they are cast when they occur,
>   and cannot be passed from one function to the next

**EDIT:**

The linked solution will allow you to just write  `c("1", "2", "ABC") %W>% as.numeric`

[Custom pipe to silence warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475923/custom-pipe-to-silence-warnings)